# ImageLines Segmented options

Tags: image-processing

I have tried utilising the ImageLines function, and its accompanying Segmented setting. However, the segmentation doesn't appear to allow for its variables to be fine tuned, at least not according to the official documentation. 
For example, one may wish to restrict the segmentation to segments with lengths within a certain range, or to change the threshold below which two segments are detected instead of one. How would one do so, assuming that the Segmented setting can be fine-tuned, and if it cannot, what method would be recommended in order to achieve the aims stated above?

Comment: Can we see the code you are working on ?

Comment: After going through the documentation I can't find any option which would allow the segmentation to be restricted to lines of a certain length. The option `"Segmented"` seems only to restrict the search to already segmented lines (white).

Comment: I haven't written any code to analyse the pictures, since the default ImageLines without any options for segmentation would not work. The pictures in question are immunofluorescently labelled DNA formed via DNA combing.

Comment: You can change the threshold below which two segments are detected rather than one, by using the (optional) third parameter of `ImageLines`. To locate lines of certain sizes, simply find them all and reject those that are not the right length.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not available in `ImageLines` in the sense that you can only select from the detected segments a posteriori, not guide the detection by restricting the range of allowed segments.

To build your application with fine-tuned controls, you need to use available building blocks like the Hough transform (`Radon[image, Method->"Hough"]`), followed by peak detection (`Binarize`, `MaxDetect`, ...), and so forth.